# Intellij: Project has two names?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've been moving things around between multiple repositories and refactoring things, now one of my projects seems to have two names? Not sure what this means or how to fix it.

The unbolded one is the correct project name, the bolded one in brackets is another repository that I don't think should be there.

[image]

Comment: Does https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206171329-How-to-hide-iml-name-in-bold-and-in-square-brackets-next-to-module-folder- gives you information ? is there any kind of module for you ?

Comment: Does it happen when you cleanly reimport the project or is it a result of manual module rename? Does it affect the root module?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by ensuring my `settings.gradle` had the correct name in it.

Comment: I understand your case, but if you would take the project from 3rd party, then probably the project name would be the one in `settings.gradle`, not the one used as project root folder, just saying.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the local folder, where your project is saved, has a different name than your project in your gradle/maven configurations. Also make sure you check your name in your Project Sturcture. That means the name from your modules and your project